# Python: Random sequence

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import string
import random

d =[random.choice(string.uppercase) for x in xrange(3355)]
s = "".join(d)

print s
```

At the moment it prints out a random sequence of letters from the alphabet. But, i need it to print out a sequence of letters containing only four letters for example 'A', 'C', 'U', 'G'. How would this be accomplished?

Thanks

Quinn

Comment: Are you making random RNA sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the set you are asking `random.choice` to pick from:

```
import random

d =[random.choice('ACUG') for x in xrange(3355)]
s = "".join(d)

print s
```

---

**Edit:** As SilentGhost points out, if your ultimate goal is only to make a string, skipping the intermediate list is more memory-efficient:

```
s = "".join(random.choice('ACUG') for x in xrange(3355))
```

Comment: you don't need a list comprehension there

Answer (score 1):

just replace `string.uppercase` with the sequence (list or string, for example) containing your choices.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  Do you mean that you want to choose a string only 4 in length?  If so then do:

```
d =[random.choice(string.uppercase) for x in xrange(4)]
```

Or if you want to choose from a list of only four choices, then do:

```
d =[random.choice("ACUG") for x in xrange(3355)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the OP is wanting to pre-select a 4-character sample from string.uppercase, then create a 3355 item string based on that:

```
import string
import random

num_samples = 4
char_sample = random.sample(string.uppercase, num_samples)
d =[random.choice(char_sample) for x in xrange(3355)]
s = "".join(d)

print s
print char_sample
```

In this case, random.sample(population, sample_count) will take care of that first requirement quite nicely.

However, I agree with the other answers/comments that this question is a bit vague.